# Unity - Move to new position + left in direction of camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

how can I move an object from the current position to the destination position + left or right (in the forward direction)?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isnt very clear - is this in the editor, at run time, is the "forward" position relative to its or the cameras? what have you tried?

Comment: No code?  See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

[unity follows the left-hand rule for cross-products](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html),
so take the cross-product of the up vector and the forward vector.

Often in unity the "up" vector can be taken as `Vector3.up`, or you may want to use the camera's own Up vector: `myCamera.transform.up`. Ditto, forward.

Depending on your situation you may want to normalize the result as well.

```
Vector3 right = Vector3.Cross(up, forward)
Vector3 left  = -right;
```